# Disable only page reload on href onlick on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with Bootstrap nav-bar tabs. When the user clicks on the navbars I want to change the URL (example: localhost:3000/users -> localhost:3000/users?name='test'). I was able to get that done by addding the link on the **href** but when I click on the tab it reloads the page. I don't want it to reload the page.

I tried preventing default with **onclick 'return false;'** but it never changes URL on the URL bar.

I know how to solve this with click listener and manually changing the URL on the URL bar. But seems like it should be easier than that.

Is there a way to just disable the page reload but keep the other properties of that link?

Comment: Have you considered using hashtags instead?  `localhost:3000/users#test` would allow you to get the value with `window.location.hash` for usage, and hash tags inheriently do not cause a page reload.

Comment: What about `#?name='test'`. It makes the query part become client side, but I guess in your case is not an issue.

Comment: I can't use hashtags the URL has to be the same as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Try with replaceState, it only changes the current url address without loading it:

```
window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, "/" + "users?name='test'");
```

Comment: From my understanding he wants to change it upon tab click, do i need to add an .on('click', function(){  in the answer?

Comment: No, that's the point. He said: "*I know how to solve this with click listener and manually changing the URL*". He's looking for a way to cancel the page reload while the URL updates automatically. (And I don't think there is one)

Comment: Idk how i missed that part, he edited? Probably because I consider "manually" to be someone typing it and "programmatically" to be the code doing it, so i must misinterpreted it on a first read.

Comment: Yeah I meant pro-grammatically by bad.